# formatting/partitioning: Ubuntu installer vs GParted vs gnome-disks utility

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, format, gnome-disk-utility

Ready to format/partition a 120GB SSD that has been securely erased by use of `hdparm` and install Ubuntu Studio 16.04 (currently running from a live USB).

Should this be done via the Ubuntu installer itself , GParted or the gnome-disks utility perhaps? Are there any pros/cons?

Comment: I believe this a subjective question. It depends on your linux experience. Ubuntu installer should be the 'easiest' way for beginners. Advanced users may prefer GParted. Very advanced users may prefer doing it directly from command line interface. Just do it the way you can or know how (to do it).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended/easiest way is to boot Ubuntu (Studio) from the live USB and either simply let the automatic installer (install Ubuntu 16.04 and let the installer do the partitioning for you) or, when it asks you how you want to partition, click 'Something Else' and use the installer's manual partitioner that comes up. Naturally I would expect that you would know what you're doing if you take that option!

I think you can also try running GNOME Disks from the Live USB if you want to try that. And you might be able to install Gparted to the live USB to run that ([apparently you need to select 'stored in reserved space' when creating the live USB via Startup Disk Creator to do this](https://askubuntu.com/a/20503/125220)) or you can use [Gparted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to partition the SSD beforehand, but this is more complex.

Really, just use the installer. I can't give any proper run-down on pros and cons (you'll need to wait for someone else to answer if you want that) but I can say that using the installer to partition is recommended and probably easiest.

If you have any serious problems (by this I mean a proper issue, not "I don't like how the installer does this") with partitioning with the installer, then try and reproduce the problem by running the installer after clicking 'Try Ubuntu' (instead of 'Install Ubuntu) at the start and running the `ubuntu-bug ubiquity` command in Terminal preferably after reproducing the bug (make sure you've connected to the Internet). Then the developers can try to fix the bug.

Comment: @ Ads20000 GParted is included in the live USB OS and Gnome Disks I can install (I've already done it once), but once I reboot it's gone, of course. Anyway, thanks for your answer; I guess I'll go with the installer. I was rather wondering whether all three alternatives would offer me the same options as to filesystems, various kind of partitions (/, /swap, /home, /boot) and the like.

Comment: Yeah I don't really know sorry. Hopefully someone will post a post on here which answers your question better but, as I said, the installer is recommended and easiest.